# Unable to get huge data response from the web-service android?

Tags: android, web-services

Can anyone tell me what this log-cat is demanding for?
Right now i am trying to consume one web-service(*which is done in dot-net*) in android.
Meanwhile that web-service is returning huge data response. When i am calling that web-service its returning few response and got crash(Application stopped unfortunately) and displaying issues like the below log-cat.

Suggestion please

Thanks for your precious time!.

**LOGCAT**

```
06-19 11:07:14.080: E/JavaBinder(2141): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141): Second failure launching  org.twinkletech.postcourier/.MainActivity, giving up
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:742)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:842)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4535)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:4613)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:375)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1752)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
06-19 11:07:14.085: E/ActivityManager(2141):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-19 11:07:14.155: E/Launcher(2659): Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something you need to rethink about your client/server comms. This link explains what's going on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html

Comment: As per your suggestion,i understood Service concept is the way to solve this issue right?..

Comment: Can you please send me atlest one example to consume webservice using service

Comment: I don't think using a service makes any difference. You need to rethink the amount of data you send from your web service at once. What kind of data is it. Can these data be broken up into smaller chunks?

Comment: I am getting response data as Json string

Comment: Ok. Is it a big list of items? In such case you should think about some pagination techniques to send only parts of that list at a time and getting the client requesting further pages.

Comment: @kgandroid i can't able to visit your link,showing 404, file not found error

Comment: Google for TransactionTooLargeException. Should be the first on the list